# How to submit cosmos script using ADL

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am working on submitting a cosmos script using azure data lake, i was created a "Data Lake Analytics" with the name "cpprodactivityreportsc08" in azure portal and trying to submit cosmos script by selecting target VC is"cpprodactivityreportsc08" through Visual studio, but i am getting below error.

"Job type 'Scope' is not supported by API-version '2017-09-01-preview'"

Comment: In order to investigate further, could you please share the script which you are running along with the screenshot of the error message?

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Job type 'Scope' is not supported by `API-version '2017-09-01-preview'`.

Please try with `API-version '2018-06-01'`.

Comment: Where do you change the API-version?